# Transform an NxN matrix into a diagonal with google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

What is the Google Spreadsheets formula to create a diagonal matrix of a 65x65 matrix? The matrix is located in a table named "table_name" and the values are between cells B10 and BN74. The diagonal matrix only contains the values of the diagonal of the original table.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B10:BN74)=COLUMN(B10:BN74); table_name!B10:BN74; 0))
```

### Example of what I want

Matrix 1 (Input):

```
[[0.16595599 0.78837343 0.94121201 0.9733295 ]
 [0.61527215 0.61785812 0.57019677 0.72195175]
 [0.22426931 0.29664025 0.11872772 0.31798318]
 [0.41426299 0.0641475  0.69247212 0.56660145]]
```

Matrix 2 (Output):

```
[[0.16595599 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.61785812 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.11872772 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         0.56660145]]
```

This query it's giving me a bad answer, a matrix mostly full of zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to offset the results of the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` functions.

Without offsets, `=ROW(B10)` will return 10, while `=COLUMN(B10)` will return 2. You'll need to offset the row number by -9 and the column number by -1 in order to compare them meaningfully within the range.

Try this:

`=ArrayFormula(IF((ROW(B10:BN74)-9)=(COLUMN(B10:BN74)-1); table_name!B10:BN74; 0))`

(You should probably include `table_name` in all the range references, or (better) use a named range for the matrix's range. It would also be advisable to obtain the offsets dynamically from the top left cell of the range, but that's getting beyond the scope of the question.)

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that by *The matrix is located in a table named "table_name"* you mean it's located in a **tab** called 'table name', this is an opportunity to employ the esoteric MUNIT function:

```
=arrayformula(let(
tbl,table_name!B10:BN74,
munit(rows(tbl))*tbl))
```

If you're in a European locale (which I'm wondering given your use of semicolons to separate the arguments in the formula in your question), replace the commas in my answer with semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
=let(Σ;columns(table_name!B:BN);
       makearray(Σ;Σ;lambda(r;c;if(index(sequence(Σ);r)=index(sequence(1;Σ);;c);index(table_name!B10:BN;r;c);0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe could simplify to =let(Σ,columns(table_name!B:E),
       makearray(Σ,Σ,lambda(r,c,if(r=c,index(table_name!B2:E,r,c),0))))